# First AJAX example won't run

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have started working my way through the AJAX tutorial on the W3Schools website and my first example won't even run.  Why won't this run please?  It opens up in the browser but nothing happens when I click the button.

The tutorial URL;

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_ie

Here is my HTML page that I created in Notepad++

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>

<p id="demo">Let AJAX change this text.</p>

<button type="button" onClick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script>
  function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for modern browsers
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6 and IE5
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
 }
};
 xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
 xhttp.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I run the HTML page by selecting Run >> chrome in Notepad++ (but tried Firefox and IE too).  The ajax_info.txt file is in the same location as the HTML file.  Here is its contents;

AJAX is not a programming language.

AJAX is a technique for accessing web servers from a web page.

AJAX stands for Asyncronous JavaScript And XML.

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser debugger? Maybe you also need an web server for doing such requests.

Comment: @alpham8 no errors.  The tutorial says nothing about a web server.  I have edited the questions with "it opens in the browser but nothing happens when I click the button"

Comment: Does it work with this url: https://www.w3schools.com/js/ajax_info.txt ?

Comment: Its working as expected.Check file location

Comment: @alpham8 tried that but it says file not found.  I have Apache installed and so will investigate running it through its localhost and port number

Comment: open the url in your browser and you will get the txt file. I just tried it before, it works...

Comment: @alpham8 Hmmm!!! Just directly clicked on the URL you supplied and it does open but when I have that URL in code it doesn't work

Comment: yeah sorry, my bad. I forgot about CORS. You cannot make cross origin ajax request. You need jsonp then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.  I installed Apache and set port to 7777 (because already had IIS on port 80) and placed files in htdocs location of apache and used the url http://localhost:7777/htdocslocation/FirstAJAXExample.html and it worked.

Comment: why you don't us IIS then? For your simple example it doesn't matter if it runs under IIS or apache. Choose one platform and delete the other. Two web servers on the same system is bad practice. PS: And for IIS you got the IIS Manager, a very nice GUI tool to manage IIS.

Answer (score 1):

you must change `xhhtp.onreadystatechange` instead of `xhttp.onreadystatechange` and `xhhtp.send();` instead of `xhttp.send();`

```
function loadDoc() {
    debugger;
  var xhhtp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  // code for modern browsers
    xhhtp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
    // code for IE6 and IE5
    xhhtp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
 }
};
 xhhtp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
 xhhtp.send();
}
```

Comment: Changed that but still same outcome.  Thanks though

Comment: If you directly opened html page then normally this error because you need a server. I think, you use npm http-server. I runned that code without error.

Comment: Thanks.  I have apache installed and so will ry running this through apache localhost and port number.  will investigate

Answer (score 0):

Because of the typo xhhtp instead of xhttp.

Comment: I have corrected the error - thanks for highlighting that but still makes no difference.  I have amended the question saying "it opens in the browser but nothing happens when I click the button"

Comment: After the typo correction it's working like a charme in my chrome-browser. The script is served from a laravel-elixir-server in my test environment.

Comment: Thanks Tobias - I have apache installed so I will try investigating running through its local host and port number

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on CORS. For example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Your can see your code working if you run a local web server, which serves the html file in question (keep the txt file in the same directory as the html file).

If you are on a mac, an easy way to run a local web server is to run the following code from where your html file is:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8001`

then in your browser go to
http://localhost:8001/yourhtmlfile.html

Since you mentioned notepad++, seems you are not on mac, but some light googling will give you a similar setting for windows.

Comment: Thanks.  Your answer is interesting for debugging when I get to learn more about this.  I have apache installed so will look at running through its local host

Comment: why python? Mac has an bundled apache